# Matching all of a certain character after a Positive Lookbehind

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been trying to get the regex right for this all morning long and I have hit the wall. In the following string I wan't to match every forward slash which follows `.com/<first_word>` with the exception of any `/` *after* the URL.

```
$string = "http://example.com/foo/12/jacket Input/Output";
    match------------------------^--^
```

The length of the words between slashes should not matter.

Regex: `(?<=.com\/\w)(\/)` results:

```
$string = "http://example.com/foo/12/jacket Input/Output"; // no match
$string = "http://example.com/f/12/jacket Input/Output";   
    matches--------------------^
```

Regex: `(?<=\/\w)(\/)` results:

```
$string = "http://example.com/foo/20/jacket Input/O/utput"; // misses the /'s in the URL
    matches----------------------------------------^
$string = "http://example.com/f/2/jacket Input/O/utput"; // don't want the match between Input/Output
    matches--------------------^-^--------------^
```

Because the lookbehind can have no modifiers and needs to be a zero length assertion I am wondering if I have just tripped down the wrong path and should seek another regex combination.

Is the positive lookbehind the right way to do this? Or am I missing something other than copious amounts of coffee?

*NOTE*: tagged with <kbd>PHP</kbd> because the regex should work in *any* of the `preg_*` functions.

Comment: The`preg_match` function returns one match. You say you need to match all characters there are after some pattern. You should use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: I still have an impression it is an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? Why match those slashes? You could url_parse the URL, and then do whatever you please. Explode, e.g.

Comment: No, it isn't an XY problem @WiktorStribiżew as the regex should work in *any* of the `preg_*` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `preg_replace` then this regex should work:

```
$re = '~(?:^.*?\.com/|(?<!^)\G)[^/\h]*\K/~';
$str = "http://example.com/foo/12/jacket Input/Output";
echo preg_replace($re, '|', $str);
//=> http://example.com/foo|12|jacket Input/Output
```

Thus replacing each `/` by a `|` after first `/` that appears after starting `.com`.

Negative Lookbehind `(?<!^)` is needed to avoid replacing a string without starting `.com` like `/foo/bar/baz/abcd`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD6wZ2/4)

Comment: The problem with this is that you're replacing the the `/` in the portion of the string with `Input/Output`

Comment: It should only be the slashes *after* foo, but not in anything not in the URL

Comment: There is a URL in the string, as well as some other data. The slashes in the other data should not be affected.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\K` here along with `\G`.grab the `groups`.

```
^.*?\.com\/\w+\K|\G(\/)\w+\K
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aT3kG2/6

```
$re = "/^.*?\\.com\\/\\w+\\K|\\G(\\/)\\w+\\K/m"; 
$str = "http://example.com/foo/12/jacket Input/Output"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

`Replace`

```
$re = "/^.*?\\.com\\/\\w+\\K|\\G(\\/)\\w+\\K/m"; 
$str = "http://example.com/foo/12/jacket Input/Output"; 
$subst = "|"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: For whatever reason this is not working in the context of `preg_match()`

Comment: OK - `preg_match_all()` works but other `preg....` functions fail - like `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the only problem with replace is one extra replacement will happend at the end....guess that will have to be dealt separately

Comment: I got this as the return `http://example.com/foo|/12/jacket Input/Output`using your code. Note that none of the slashes have been removed, but a pipe has been added. Even in your substitution example the slashes are left in place. I *really* appreciate your help with this, it seems that we're both beating our heads against the wall. One of the +1's is mine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard we can do it like this ...u just need to remove an extra `|` later. https://regex101.com/r/aT3kG2/8

Comment: Can you also copy those regex's into your answer. They may not stay on regex101 for ever! Which would make your answers useless to others

Comment: That last example you provded added spaces and an extra pipe @vks `http://example.com/foo||12|jacket|wow`

Answer (score 1):

Another [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) based idea.

```
$re = '~(?:^\S+\.com/\w|\G(?!^))\w*+\K/~';
```

- The `(:` [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group)  to set *entry point* `^\S+\.com/\w` or [glue matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) `\G(?!^)` to it.
- `\w*+\K/` [possessively](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) matches any amount of word characters until a slash. `\K` [resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) match.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dL0zQ1/1)